# Responsive table mobile, header of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a responsive table. On small devices, it's td, th elements' styles are `display:block`.

But in this case, the header of the table is reflected at the very top, and not before every item. How to make it, so that on mobile devices I have got the structure of the table-item header, table header-item?

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
            td, th {
                display: block;
                padding-left: 0 !important;
            }
        }
```

```html
<table width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>№</span></th>
            <th><span>Date</span></th>
            <th><span>Adress</span></th>
            <th><span>Price</span></th>
            <th><span>Status</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>13.12.2017</span></td>
            <td><span>Street</span></td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <span>299</span>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Received</span>
                <span class="brackets">13.12.2017</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>13.12.2017</span></td>
            <td><span>Street</span></td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <span>299</span>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Received</span>
                <span class="brackets">13.12.2017</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>13.12.2017</span></td>
            <td><span>Street</span></td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <span>299</span>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Received</span>
                <span class="brackets">13.12.2017</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

change you css to this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
            td, th {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 15px !important;
            }
        }
```

snippet down

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
            td, th {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 15px !important;
            }
        }
```

```html
<table width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>№</span></th>
            <th><span>Date</span></th>
            <th><span>Adress</span></th>
            <th><span>Price</span></th>
            <th><span>Status</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>13.12.2017</span></td>
            <td><span>Street</span></td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <span>299</span>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Received</span>
                <span class="brackets">13.12.2017</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>13.12.2017</span></td>
            <td><span>Street</span></td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <span>299</span>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Received</span>
                <span class="brackets">13.12.2017</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><span>1</span></td>
            <td><span>13.12.2017</span></td>
            <td><span>Street</span></td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <span>299</span>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Received</span>
                <span class="brackets">13.12.2017</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I need display: block